# При активации одновременном двух плагинов на WordPress происходит ошибка

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

На движке WordPress установлены два плагина(кастомные типы), при активации обоих страница, на которой должна загружаться главная страница одного из типов,редиректится на главную страницу сайта.В дебаге обнаруживаеться такая ошибка.

**
setDocument

Приостановлено на исключении
SyntaxError: '*,:x' is not a valid selector**

обьясните пожалуйста в чем проблема,очень желательна работа обоих типов на движке.
Спасибо!

Comment: Что за плагины?

Comment: Один Psychological tests & quizzes, а второй Prime Catalog.

Comment: Если перестаёт работать Wp-testing, то пишет: "не верный тип записи", а если перестаёт работать Prime Catalog, то вместо страницы с картой открывается главная страница сайта (при этом все внутренние страницы каталога работают).

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что где-то, в каком-то плагине не верно обращения к селектору `*,:x` из `javascript`, в скорей всего `jquery` - такой селектор не корректен.

Comment: Насколько реально это исправить самому?Либо это нужно обращаться к разработчикам плагина?

Comment: На столько, на сколько знаете `js-jquery`.

Comment: Спасибо за ваши ответы